# Define a key to generate keys

Tags: java, macos, security, aes, secret-key

I'm making a project about security in Java. The Server receives a password and with this password is supposed to insert in MAC to verify the consistency of one specific file.

```
Mac m;
SecretKey sk;
sk = KeyGenerator.getInstance( "AES" ).keygenerator();/* what i don't want to use */
byte[]mac=null;
Mac m = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
m.init( password ); /* it's wrong */
m.update("work of security".getBytes());
mac = m.doFinal();
```

What I can understand is how to define a `SecretKey` to MAC init...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two typical methods use to derive an AES key from a password are:

1. Using the raw bytes of the password. This option is not very strong (subject to trivial [dictionary attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_attack)) and relies on the password being exactly 128/192/256 bits.
2. Deriving the key using a function, such as PBKDF2.

You need to find out how the key is derived. The two options in code are:

**Raw Bytes**

```
SecretKey aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(password.getBytes(someCharset), "AES");
```

**Derivation Function**

Example PBKDF2:

```
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
SecretKey aesKey = factory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(password, salt,
      iterations, 256));
```

The `salt` value is a random byte array (i.e. perhaps eight bytes). The `iterations` can be increased to improve security at the expense of performance.

Comment: If you use the password directly as a key, an attacker can very quickly check a dictionary of common passwords. The key derivation process makes it impossible to pre-compute a dictionary of keys, and much slower to check a dictionary.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I'll try this right now!
What is the difference between SecretKeyFactory and SecretKey?